# People have missed the entire point of the question about bad gay guys in movies

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions

[This](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/101871/gay-being-bad-guy-in-a-movie) was not a list question by whoever wrote it. 
It was making the point that the culture of cinema has most of the time had gay guys as good guys. So the OP asked for exceptions. Asking for exceptions is not asking for a list. The people who voted for that off topic have missed the broad intent.

To me, this was a valid and interesting question. The OP was NOT asking for a movie recommendation. Where in the OP did he or she ask that?

Comment: So what will be the answer? Because there are already three answers with 2 being yes and one being unclear. But for myself, I can give 2/3 example from my head and many more by googling. But I didn't like the close reason myself

Answer (score 8):

> Asking for exceptions is not asking for a list.

### Yes, it is....

It's *essentially* asking for a *list* of exceptions.

What this means is that there will be possibly many individual *different* answers which actually makes the question **too broad**.

In general our ideal Q&A has a *single* correct answer not multiple answers from multiple sources.

I will grant that the "recommendation" close reason is erroneous.

I can't recall how I voted (I may have piled on in error or voted "Too Broad") but it should still be closed as "Too Broad".

---

There is the basis of a good [analysis](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) question here on the portrayal of homosexual/non-binary/etc. characters etc in movies but...

> Is there some movie where gay character is actually a bad guy?

Is not the way to go about it.